# use awk revise the original file, can not get right result

Tags: awk

The file has 200 lines and every line is the same:

```
first,second,third
```

When I run

```
awk -F"," '{$2="new second";print $0 > FILENAME}' OFS="," test
```

I will get 214 lines. And the last 16 lines are

```
201 ,new second,third
202 first,new second,third
203 first,new second,third
204 first,new second,third
205 first,new second,third
206 first,new second,third
207 first,new second,third
208 first,new second,third
209 first,new second,third
210 first,new second,third
211 first,new second,third
212 first,new second,third
213 first,new second,third
214 fi,new second
```

I've been in this situation which means the result is not right many times.Each time will reduce line numbers.But this example adds line numbers and some lines are wrong:

```
,new second,third
fi,new second
```

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirection to the same file while processing it leads to your strange results.

If you want to overwrite your original file, you could redirect the output to a new file and move it back afterwards:

```
awk -F"," '{$2="new second";print > FILENAME".new"}' OFS="," test && mv test.new test
```

or

```
awk -F"," '{$2="new second";print}' OFS="," test > test.new && mv test.new test
```

Comment: Thks. Will all bash commands lead to strange results when try to revise the original file? And do not reconmend to revise the original file? Use `sed -i` or `sort -o`, the result is always right.

Comment: With GNU awk you can use `awk -i inplace`, that works too. You will always run into problems if you write to a file while you're reading from it if there is no explicit "in-place" option.

Comment: note that "behind the scenes", most programs with in-place edit options either write to a temp file and rename it, or store the modified file in memory and write on exit (or close).   `-i` is just a convenience so you don't have to do that yourself.

Comment: @tranquil.coder Writing to the same file that you are reading from will cause issues as soon as what you're writing is not exactly as much as you are reading. If the writing file pointer "overtakes" the reading file pointer, you will start to read what you recently wrote. This is why programs that implements "in-place" edits do so using temporary files (most of the time).

Comment: there's also `sponge` from [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) - which can be used as a generic "edit-in-place" tool for programs that don't have a `-i` or similar feature.  Or even for those that do.  Wherever possible, it preserves ownership, permissions, and inode number (so doesn't break hard links and is therefore better than most `-i` options).

Answer (score 0):

You can find answer in the two links.
[save-modifications-in-place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529716/save-modifications-in-place-with-awk)

> In latest GNU Awk (since 4.1.0 released), it has the option of "inplace" file editing:

[awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html)

> Version 4.1 of gawk introduced the following features:
>   The -i and --include options load awk library files.